# Sampling with repetition in Python

Tags: python

I have a string with 50ish elements, I need to randomize this and generate a much longer string, I found `random.sample()` to only pick unique elements, which is great but not fit for my purpose, is there a way to allow repetitions in Python or do I need to manyally build a cycle?

Comment: Why doesnt random.sample() fit your purpose exactly?

Comment: @AntonvBR it picks uniques, so if my list lenght is K and I need any number greater than K it gives an error, does not allor repetition.

Comment: If one of the provided answers works for you, please mark it as accepted.

Comment: May anybody explain me why is it in fact called Sampling with replacement instead of Sampling with repetition?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

You can use [`numpy.random.choice`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.14.0/reference/generated/numpy.random.choice.html). It has an argument to specify how many samples you want, and an argument to specify whether you want replacement. Something like the following should work.

```
import numpy as np
choices = np.random.choice([1, 2, 3], size=10, replace=True)
# array([2, 1, 2, 3, 3, 1, 2, 2, 3, 2])
```

If your input is a string, say something like `my_string = 'abc'`, you can use:

```
choices = np.random.choice([char for char in my_string], size=10, replace=True)
# array(['c', 'b', 'b', 'c', 'b', 'a', 'a', 'a', 'c', 'c'], dtype='<U1')
```

Then get a new string out of it with:

```
new_string = ''.join(choices)
# 'cbbcbaaacc'
```

### Performance

Timing the three answers so far and [`random.choices`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/random.html#random.choices) from the comments (skipping the `''.join` part since we all used it) producing 1000 samples from the string `'abc'`, we get:

- `numpy.random.choice([char for char in 'abc'], size=1000, replace=True)`:

  > 34.1 µs ± 213 ns per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 10000 loops each)
- `random.choices('abc', k=1000)`

  > 269 µs ± 4.27 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1000 loops each)
- `[random.choice('abc') for _ in range(1000)]`:

  > 924 µs ± 10.4 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1000 loops each)
- `[random.sample('abc',1)[0] for _ in range(1000)]`:

  > 4.32 ms ± 67.3 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 100 loops each)

Numpy is fastest by far. If you put the `''.join` parts in there, you actually see numpy and `random.choices` neck and neck, with both being three times faster than the next fastest for this example.

Comment: did you test `random.choices` with `k` argument to indicate the lenght?

Comment: I got `269 us +/- 6.43 us` per loop for `random.choices([char for char in 'abc'], k=1000)`. Numpy is still fastest.

Comment: How did you measure the time taken and what does the `replace` argument do?

Comment: @S.Redrum I measured time taken using the @timeit macro in a Jupyter notebook. It automates running a bunch of iterations of the same command and giving timing statistics. The `replace` argument just means that it samples with repetition, so it doesn't exhaust the list while it's sampling. I.e., elements can be repeated.

Answer (score 1):

You could do something like this:

```
import random
dict = 'abcdef'
''.join([random.choice(dict) for x in range(50)])
```

Answer (score 0):

Not saying this is the most effective (you should prob. use choice here) ... but consider it:

```
import random
a = ['a','b','c']
' '.join([random.sample(a,1)[0] for _ in range(6)])
```

Answer (score 0):

I have found this, I forgot to mention I was on Python 3.6:

```
DICTIONARY_NUMBERS_HEX = ['0', '1', '2', '3', '4', '5', '6', '7', '8', '9', 'A', 'B', 'C', 'D', 'E', 'F']
block_text = "".join(random.choices(DICTIONARY_NUMBERS_HEX,k=50)
```

Using `k=50` named argument will generate repeated elements.